# widgets freezing after minimise window

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, qmainwindow

I am using Qt5 Creator for an app, and in the main window's constructor I call `this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized)`. The radio buttons and the check box work fine (i.e. easily toggle between checked and unchecked) when the window is initially maximized.

However, if I minimize it and maximize it then the radio buttons and the check box seem to freeze and don't freely toggle. But if I do restore down again things become fine.

I tried including a `this->update` in the slots of the radio buttons and check box but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have GUI only without any other code?

Comment: ya code is there...but this is happening without code also I am using Qt5 Creator

Comment: Qt5 Creator? You mean Qt5 and QtCreator??

Answer (score 6):

I encountered similar problem

**Environment:** Windows7 + Qt5.3 + Frameless QMainWindow

**What I did:** Minimized window with `QMainWindow::showMinimized` then shown it again.

**What happened:** Window stopped redrawing. It looked frozen.

I was debugging it and found out following:

After minimizing window attribute `Qt::WA_Mapped` was removed from QMainWindow (you can set breakpoint to `setAttribute_internal` in `qwidget.cpp` to check it). But this attribute was not set again after showing window. This caused that condition `if (discardSyncRequest(tlw, tlwExtra))` in `QWidgetBackingStore::sync` was not met and it caused `dirtyWidgets` are not cleared. In other part of Qt updating system this caused that no other rendering was made.

**Workaround I did:** Subclassed `QMainWindow` and set attribute `Qt::WA_Mapped` manually when window was restored (handling changeEvent):

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event) {
  if(event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange) {
    if(!isMinimized()) {
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_Mapped);
    }
  }
}
```

This works for me well. Right solution would be probably fixing the bug in Qt.

**More about the problem**

I found similar bug in Qt project history (marked as closed):
[QTBUG-34147](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34147)

Also similar question in Qt forum: [Minimizing frameless windows...](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/33570)

I found this comment beside the mentioned condition in `QWidgetBackingStore::sync`

```
// If the top-level is minimized, it's not visible on the screen so we can delay the
// update until it's shown again. In order to do that we must keep the dirty states.
// These will be cleared when we receive the first expose after showNormal().
// However, if the widget is not visible (isVisible() returns false), everything will
// be invalidated once the widget is shown again, so clear all dirty states.
```

It seems that there was a bug in Qt kernel (maybe mentioned QTBUG-34147) which was solved, but there remained some issues around it.

Comment: Fascinating! I've just discovered this post and it solved a problem I've been dealing with for ages, thanks!

Comment: I had this problem when adding libvlc to the widget even without minimizing. I wish I could give more than one upvote.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);` you are possibly overriding other states property of the windows. In particular, you are removing `Qt::WindowActive`. So use either of

```
this->setWindowState(this->windowState() | Qt::WindowMaximized);
this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized | Qt::WindowActive);
```

But I wonder why you are playing around with window state. Can't you use `show()` in the constructor to make your window visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try `this->showMaximized()` instead. The window state is available for doing tricky things that aren't possible through any other method, but if another method provides the desired functionality (QWidget::showMaximized() in this case) use that instead.